# When running python script to import code to invoke the UI design and display i have no errors but i dont get a display

Tags: pyqt4

Good day, Please can someone assist, i have to add 2 calendars to my U.I, a birthday calendar and a 2019 calendar.
When i run the python script i don't receive any errors, nothing happens. It doesn't display the U.I design.

The first code is the .ui converted to .py and the code thereafter is the code to invoke and display the U.I Design, but nothing happens, please can someone help me, i am new to Python and i am really struggling.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(704, 580)
        self.calendarWidget = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 10, 280, 155))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Script MT Bold"))
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.calendarWidget.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calendarWidget"))
        self.calendarWidget_2 = QtGui.QCalendarWidget(Dialog)
        self.calendarWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 220, 280, 155))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Script MT Bold"))
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.calendarWidget_2.setFont(font)
        self.calendarWidget_2.setSelectedDate(QtCore.QDate(2019, 3, 27))
        self.calendarWidget_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calendarWidget_2"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 220, 101, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit(Dialog)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 380, 91, 21))
        self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2019, 3, 27), QtCore.QTime(0, 0, 0)))
        self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate(2019, 3, 27))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit"))
        self.dateEdit_2 = QtGui.QDateEdit(Dialog)
        self.dateEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 170, 91, 21))
        self.dateEdit_2.setDate(QtCore.QDate(2019, 2, 22))
        self.dateEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateEdit_2"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 71, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 510, 141, 16))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 530, 111, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 430, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 380, 181, 16))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))
        self.label_6 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 460, 81, 16))
        self.label_6.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_6"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 460, 91, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.label_7 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 170, 91, 16))
        self.label_7.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_7"))
        self.label_8 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 170, 51, 16))
        self.label_8.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_8"))
        self.label_9 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 380, 46, 13))
        self.label_9.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_9"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Birthday Calendar", None))
        self.dateEdit.setDisplayFormat(_translate("Dialog", "d/m/yyyy", None))
        self.dateEdit_2.setDisplayFormat(_translate("Dialog", "d/m/yyyy", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "2019 Calendar", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Marelize Jansen van Vuuren", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Student no: 60858753", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Calculate Age", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select DOB and Calculate exact age", None))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Current Age", None))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Select today\'s date", None))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Dialog", "D/MM/YYY", None))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Dialog", "D/MM/YY", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This is the code to invoke and display the user interface

```
import sys
from dispcalendar import*

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.calendarWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged()'), self.dispdate)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.calendarWidget_2, QtCore.SIGNAL('selectionChanged()'), self.dispdate)
        self.dispdate()

    def dispdate(self):
        self.ui.dateEdit_2.setDate(self.ui.calendarWidget.selectedDate())
        self.ui.dateEdit.setDate(self.ui.calendarWidget_2.selectedDate())
        self.ui.dateEdit_2.display(text)
        self.ui.dateEdit.display(text)
        self.ui.calendarWidget.display(text)
        self.ui.calendarWidget_2.display(text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The code looks fine, are you sure you're running the right file? Do you see any output at all when you run it?

Comment: no, theres nothing, it runs and shows nothing